# Create NSMutableArray with NSDictionary elements slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

This chunk of code is a method that creates an array for use by multiple other classes. Input is an array from a CoreData fetch, of type NSDictionaryResultType.

3 of the fields are strings that I need to break into arrays, thus the componentsSeparatedByString.

The resulting array, _dataProductionArray, works great --- BUT --- this chunk of code takes a FULL 5 SECONDS to process for about 32,000 records.

Any help pointing out glaring mistakes that are causing this slow performance would be greatly appreciated!!

```
NSMutableArray *dataArray = [NSMutableArray array];
int j = 0;
int maxNumMonths = 0;
for (id obj in _dictionaries) {
    if ([_dictionaries[j] [@"month"] length] >0 ) {
        // get production values
        NSArray *aItems   = [_dictionaries[j] [@"prodA"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        NSArray *bItems   = [_dictionaries[j] [@"prodB"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        NSArray *monthItems = [_dictionaries[j] [@"month"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

        NSMutableArray *productionAArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSMutableArray *productionBArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        int monthLoop = 1;
        for (NSNumber *month in monthItems) {
            if (monthLoop <= MONTHS_OF_PRODUCTION) {
                if ([month intValue] == monthLoop) {
                    [productionAArray addObject:[aItems objectAtIndex:monthLoop-1]];
                    [productionBArray addObject:[bItems objectAtIndex:monthLoop-1]];
                    productionCount ++;
                    if (monthLoop > maxNumMonths)
                        maxNumMonths = monthLoop;
                }
            }
            monthLoop++;
        }

        NSDictionary *arrayItem = @{@"name":_dictionaries[j] [@"name"],
                                    @"type":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_dictionaries[j] [@"type"]],
                                    @"height":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_dictionaries[j] [@"height"]],
                                    @"aArray":productionAArray,
                                    @"bArray":productionBArray,
                                    };
        [dataArray addObject:arrayItem];
    }
    j++;
}

_dataProductionArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:dataArray];
```

Comment: You have a couple of nested loops here, so anything you can move out of the loops will help your performance.  You might want to try creating productionAArray and productionBArray outside the loops, and just do removeObjects at their current creation point.  I think one of your other problems is that you're creating a whole lot of objects in tight loops that won't be deallocated until you're completely done.  Instead of looping through 32000 of these records, how about if you created 32 threads that each processed only 1000 records, and segmented it so only a maximum of 5 threads could run.

Comment: 5 seconds for 32,000 records sounds reasonable.

Comment: Thanks Hot Licks - kind of what I was suspecting. Have tried different strategies to optimize, and nothing made it markedly faster.  Owen, did try some multi-threading, but either I did it wrong, or it just didn't help. When the same code runs for few iterations, speed is not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a few optimizations you could do in the loop, but I'm not sure how much these would help (especially if the compiler is doing them anyway).  The root problem is that 32k is a lot of iterations.

Do you need all 32k results at once?  You could get a dramatic improvement in user experience by doing this work [lazily](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation), as the UI demands the transformed record.

This approach would be to make dataProductionArray a mutable dictionary, indexed by an NSNumber index.  Then, instead of ...

```
// replace this
self.dataProductionArray[128];

// with this
[self dataProductionAtIndex:@128];
```

That new getter method calls the code you wrote lazily, like this ...

```
- (id)dataProductionAtIndex:(NSNumber *)index {

    // replace dataProductionArray with dataProductionDictionary
    id result = self.dataProductionDictionary[index];
    if (!result) {
        result = [self getDataAt:index];
        self.dataProductionDictionary[index] = result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then `getDataAt:` is a simple refactor of the code you posted, except instead of looping 32k elements, it does the work for just one index that gets passed in....

```
- (id)getDataAt:(NSNumber *)index {

    int j = [index intValue];

    // no loop, just skip to iteration j
    NSArray *aItems   = [_dictionaries[j] [@"prodA"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSArray *bItems   = [_dictionaries[j] [@"prodB"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    // and so on, then at the end, don't save arrayItem, just return it

    NSDictionary *arrayItem = @{@"name":_dictionaries[j] [@"name"],
                                @"type":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_dictionaries[j] [@"type"]],
                                @"height":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_dictionaries[j] [@"height"]],
                                @"aArray":productionAArray,
                                @"bArray":productionBArray,
                                };
    return arrayItem;
}
```

PS - A mutable dictionary is a good data structure for lazy evaluation.  The next level of sophistication is NSCache, which acts like a mutable dictionary and also manages memory ([class ref here](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/index.html)).

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, I do need all 32k results at once. Would NSDictionary still be a better choice?

Comment: They will perform similarly, I think, with a slight advantage to the array.  Either way, we'd just be nipping at the edge of the problem.  If you need to do the work in one shot, I think your energy might be better spent on a) taking it off the main thread so your UI remains responsive, and b) a progress indicator to keep the user calm.

Comment: Thanks, danh, I did take it off the main thread, and do have an activity indicator.  Appreciate the information.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is daft. Just write

```
for (NSDictionary* dict in _dictionaries)...
```

and use dict instead of _dictionaries [j]. One method call saved each time.

`stringWithFormat:` creates a new string each time. Can't you just add the item itself instead of turning it into a string?

Instead of extracting all the items into `productionAArray` and `productionBArray`, create an `NSIndexSet`, fill it in the loop -- or better yet using a block -- and create the arrays in one go.

Comment: Haha, you are right, definitely daft...  Made those changes, doesn't affect performance, but definitely better code. Don't think NSIndexSet will work for me, the values in productionAArray are not necessarily unique, and I am using NSArray to preserve the order.